# HelixToolkit and 3d plotting

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I searched for decent library, that allow plotting surfaces of revolution.
So I found HelixToolkit, that has not only convenient wpf controls, but also big lack of documentation.

I want to create two-sheeted hyperboloid that descibed by [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwRTk.png)
but can't figure out what to use in mish-mash of functions and objects, that Helix delivers.

If you know another libraries/documentation or even solution to my problem, please, guide me.

Comment: You don't really need any extra libraries for that. You can plot [any 3D surface](https://imgur.com/SbuEJCY) simply by using built-in WPF objects, like `MeshGeometry3D`.

Comment: I tried to do it in native way, but I can't understand how to set `TriangleIndices` for complex figures. I assume that single mistake leads to blank viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/develop/Source/Examples/WPF/SurfaceDemo

Helixtoolkit has the dynamic surface 3d, maybe this is what you want.